# Kendo MVC TabStrip Tabs will not open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

My Kendo MVC TabStrip Tabs will not open. Only where selected is true will it show tab content. In this example, the Resolution and Hist tabs are not opening. No console errors.

[image]

```
  <div class="col col-lg-12">
    <section class="well" id="">
        <h1>Workflow Details</h1>

        @*https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/index*@

        @*////*@


        @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
               .Name("tabstrip")

               .Items(tabstrip =>
               {
               tabstrip.Add().Text("History")

                .Content(@<text>
            <h1>Workflow Item Action History</h1>

            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Custom.Website.Areas.Custom.Models.WorkflowItemActionHistoryModel>()
                    .Name("itemActionHistoryGrid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        //columns.Bound(c => c.WorkflowItem);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.ActionTakenByName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains))).Width(30);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Description).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains))).Width(100);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.ActionDate).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dateFormat" }).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains))).Width(30);
                    })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
                    .Filterable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                        .Refresh(true)
                        .PageSizes(true)
                        .ButtonCount(5))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Read(read => read.Action("ItemHistoryRead", "WFItem").Data("getWorkflowItemIDOBJ"))
                        .Sort(sort => { sort.Add(f => f.ActionDate).Descending(); }).ServerOperation(false)
                        .PageSize(20)
                    )
                       .Events(events => { events.DataBound("itemActionHistoryGridOnDataBound"); })
            )
        </text>);

                      tabstrip.Add().Text("Resolution")

               .Content(@<text>
                    <section class="well" id="itemFields">
                        <h1>REsolution</h1>
                        <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col col-sm-4" for="name2">Name</label>
                                <div class="col col-sm-8 col col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name2" value="Johnatan Dodsworth" class="k-textbox" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>

        </text>);
                   tabstrip.Add().Text("Attached Documents")
                   .Selected(true)
                    .Content(@<text>
                        <h1>Select File(s) To Upload</h1>
                        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                    .Name("files")
                    .TemplateId("fileTemplate")
                    .Events(events => events.Complete("onUploadSuccess"))
                    .Async(a => a
                    .Save("ItemAttachmentSubmit", "WFItem", new { workflowItemID = @Model.WorkflowItemModel.WorkflowItemID })
                            .Remove("ItemAttachmentRemove", "WFItem")
                            .AutoUpload(false)
                        )
                        )
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-sm-2"></div>
                            <div id="attachments-list" class="col col col-sm-10">

                                @(Html.Kendo().ListView<WorkflowItemAttachmentModel>()
                        .Name("AttachmentsList")
                        .TagName("div")
                        .Events(e => e.DataBound("onAttachmentsListDataBound").Change("onAttachmentsCriteriaChange"))
                        .ClientTemplateId("itemAttachmentsTemplate")

                        .DataSource(dataSource =>
                        {
                            dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("AttachmentsRead", "WFItem").Data("getWorkflowItemIDOBJ"));
                            dataSource.Sort(sort => { sort.Add(f => f.CreatedDate); }).ServerOperation(false);
                        })
                        .Selectable(s => s.Mode(ListViewSelectionMode.Single))
                                )
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </text>);
               })
        )
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: If you comment out the content of the tabs does this still happen?

Comment: @Supersnake Yes.